# spring kafka metrics value mismatch

Tags: java, apache-kafka, prometheus, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i have a kafka consumer and i'm using spring-kafka 2.8.6. I consume batch wise and my consumer looks like below.

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic", groupId = "mygroup",
          autoStartup = "true", concurrency = "3", id = "my-listener",
          containerFactory = "KafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void consume(List<ConsumerRecord> records) {

    // process messages

  }
```

For consumer i wrote a load test and i checked the metrics using defauls spring-kafka metrics. I kept a variable and got the number of messages consumed from the consumer and i checked the consumed count from the spring-kafka defauls metrics using prometheus endpoint.
I was able to find the correct metric under the name of `spring.kafka.listener` .

But when o compared the number of consumed messages from the consumer and compared it with the prometheus count, there is a small mismatch (for 3000 consumed messages, 70-100 messages were missing).

I checked the dlt topics and nothing has gone to dlt. Even if it has gone to dlt, i could have seen it in the prometheus metrics.

Is this a known issue or am i missing something ?

btw my application properties file for prometheus looks like below

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,prometheus,env
      base-path: /
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  metrics:
    web:
      server:
        request:
          autotime:
            enabled: true
            percentiles-histogram: true
    distribution:
      sla:
        http:
          server:
            requests: 300ms,500ms
```

and part of my prometheus endpoint metric looks like below

```
spring_kafka_listener_seconds Kafka Listener Timer
spring_kafka_listener_seconds summary
spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count{exception="none",name="my-listener-1",result="success",} 4730.0
spring_kafka_listener_seconds_sum{exception="none",name="my-listener-1",result="success",} 2.941328279
```

I use below dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How are you querying Prometheus server to compare? Perhaps you should plot the data over time instead of point-in-time queries?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have plot the data over time using promql and i found few messages were missing. that why i checked by calling the `mydomain/prometheus` endpoint and calculated the the container wise consumed messages. Still i can see few messages were missing.